# Ruby on rails action filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, action, device

In my application I have at this point a authentication function through oauth, but before of that I would like to have a login page, so I want to use Devise to create that. The problem that I am facing is that bought Device and my authentication method require a before_filter, and both methods redirect to a page, and because of that I get an error saying that I have to redirects. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know explicitly what you are doing and what are your actual requirements but as far as I know you don not need before filter. you need to provide both options for login, authentication with devise and Omniauth.
I am referring you to some links consult it.

Mandatory:

http://www.samionrails.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-omni-auth-with-devise-tutorial.html

Optional:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers

http://www.samionrails.blogspot.com/2013/08/authenticate-user-using-omniauth.html